# Use generics to cast from parent to child on method call

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance

I've been trying to find a way to do the following, but not sure if it's even possible. Let's say I have a super class and two subclasses with totally different and independent fields (classes `Field1` and `Field2`):

```
public abstract class Parent {
    private String field;
    // getters and setters
}

public class Child1 extends Parent {
    private Field1 field1;
}

public class Child2 extends Parent {
    private Field2 field2;
}
```

Now, I have an interface with a method that accepts the `Parent` class, and two implementations `Impl1` and `Impl2` which implement that interface, but I want them to accept the child classes:

```
public interface IMethod {
    void method(Parent parent);
}

public class Impl1 implements IMethod {
    @Override        
    public void method(Child1 child1) { // like this won't compile
        // implementation using Field1
    }
}

public class Impl2 implements IMethod {
    @Override
    public void method(Child2 child2) { // like this won't compile
        // implementation using Field2
    }
}
```

I've been trying to use generics in different ways to accomplish this, so I avoid the casting from `Parent` to the child classes inside the implementation of the method. The thing is that I'm not still very familiar with generics, so not sure if this would be possible or there's just no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
public interface IMethod {
    void method(Parent parent);
}
```

to

```
public interface IMethod<T extends Parent>{
    void  method(T parent);
}
```

and your implementations to

```
public class Impl1 implements IMethod<Child1> {
    @Override        
    public void method(Child1 child1) {
        // implementation using Field1
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Impl2 implements IMethod<Child2> {
    @Override        
    public void method(Child2 child2) {
        // implementation using Field2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several different solutions here, each with some pros and cons. e.g.:

- curiously recurring template pattern:

  ```
  interface IMethod<Child extends Parent> {
    void method(Child child);
  }

  public class Impl1 implements IMethod<Child1> {
    @Override        
    public void method(Child1 child1) {
      // implementation using Field1
    }
  }

  public class Impl2 implements IMethod<Child2> {
    @Override
    public void method(Child2 child2) {
        // implementation using Field2
    }
  }
  ```

  It is easy to implement and use but also not very flexible - each of those child classes is strictly bound to the class it accepts as an argument.
- method overload:

  ```
  interface IMethod {
    void method(Parent parent);
  }

  public class Impl implements IMethod {
    @Override        
    public void method(Parent parent) {
      // generic implementation
    }

    public void method(Child1 child1) {
      // implementation using Field1
    }

    public void method(Child2 child2) {
      // implementation using Field2
    }
  }
  ```

  This also lets you easily extends functionality - but it requires exact type of passes to be known at compile time.
- double displatch - in most OO languages implemented with a visitor pattern:

  ```
  class Parent {
    private String field;

    void visit() {
      // generic implementation
    }
  }

  public class Child1 extends Parent {
    private Field1 field1;

    @Override
    void visit() {
      // implementation using Field1
    }
  }

  interface IMethod {
    void method(Parent parent);
  }

  public class Impl implements IMethod {
    @Override        
    public void method(Parent parent) {
      parent.visit();
    }
  }
  ```

  It suits your example but requires some boilerplate.

If you are sure that you have to handle `Parent` I would recommend `visitor`. However in general you could resort to something simpler like:

```
class Parent {
  // fields

  public void handle() {
    // Parent's fields
  }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
  // fields

  @Override
  public void handle() {
    // Child's fields
  }
}
```